# Why are "ghost files" accumulating in my Recycle Bin? (Detected via SequoiaView)

Tags: windows-7, recycle-bin

Over the past several months my available Hard Drive space has seemed to gradually decrease faster than my actual usage.  I finally noticed in SequoiaView that "ghosts" of many of the files that I had previously deleted were still present in my Recycle Bin as can be viewed here:

[image: SequoiaView Screenshot]

I was also able to open the files from within SequoiaView. I was not able to view or delete the files from Windows Explorer, but when I blew away my Recycle Bin from the Command Prompt, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238953/how-to-empty-recyclebin-through-command-prompt/9239158), an extra 3.6 GB were freed up.

Can anyone help me guess what might be causing this phantom accumulation of files in my Recycle Bin?

I'm using a Windows 7 computer.  I'm the sole user, but it's on a work network with multiple user accounts.  The files that I inspected were all files that had been manually deleted by me over a period of several months.  I manually empty my Recycle Bin several times a day.

**Update:**

Manually deleting my Recycle Bin directory via the Command Prompt did appear to permanently resolve my issue, but I still can't pinpoint a cause.

```
rd /s %systemdrive%\$Recycle.bin
```

Comment: I hate this view. Post a picture of TreeSizeFree, please. This is much easier to use

Comment: Thank you.  I'll try that tool as well.  I currently no longer have ghost files in my Recycle Bin to show you though.  And deleting a file as a test did not generate a ghost file.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have learned, ghost files are nothing to be worried about and they can be written over when it needs to be.

Funfact: if your computer isn't super tight on memory then you can actually retrieve deleted files, which you have found in your case. They use this in police investigations and some jobs are based around it.

I learned about these "ghost files" because I didn't empty my recycling bin since I had bought my computer and when I did (about a week ago) it said it had found 17gb of data on it. I did some research on it to see if there was any problem with the massive 17GB, and this is what I've found (top paragraph).

Comment: In my case, my hard drive space was seemingly almost maxed and the amount listed as available on C: was misstated by 3.6 GB.  I also seemed to experience memory-related performance problems (but I can't quantify that).  This was a performance concern.